# Transitioning to a vegetarian lifestyle

Tags: vegetarian

I'm starting to transition from all red meat to fish and chicken only, and would like to move to no chicken. However, I often feel very tired and lethargic.

What foods should I start eating as a meat substitute?

Comment: I'm just gonna mention that I think this is the sort of thing which would probably be best asked to a medical professional, or at least a registered dietician, rather than on an online forum.

Answer (score 2):

I lived on a fish diet for a good year or so, it's really not that hard once you get past the initial meat cravings. Whale meat is a good substitute for beef, you should check if they have that in your area. Tuna-pasta is also a good satiating dish. Another personal favorite is salmon with fried mushrooms and mashed potatoes.

Peanut butter sandwiches, and fruits and nuts in general are good for snacks through the day.

In general, you should just try to base your diet on non-processed fish as much as possible (e.g. eating fishsticks every day is probably not a good idea).